# Don't seem to understand the cause of the error

Tags: python

trying to convert some mathematical formula to code to solve for the analysis of a four-bar mechanism

```
import math

a = input('the length of link AB\n')
a = float(a)
b = input('the length of link BC\n')
b = float(b)
c = input('the length of link CD\n')
c = float(c)
d = input('the length of link DA\n')
d = float(d)
Theta = input('Interval of the input angle in degrees\n')
Theta = float(Theta)
Theta = math.radians(Theta)
Va = input('Angular velocity of the input link AB in rad/s\n')
Va = float(Va)
Aa = input('Angular acceleration of the input link in rad/s^2\n')
Aa = float(Aa)


K1 = d/a
K2 = d/c
K3 = (a**2 - b**2 + c**2 + d**2)/2*a*c
A = (1 - K2)*math.cos(Theta) + K3 + K1
A = float(A)
B = -2*math.sin(Theta)
B = float(B)
C = K1 + K3 - (1 + K2)*math.cos(Theta)
C = float(C)


Phi1 = 2*math.degrees(math.atan((-B+(B**2 - 4*A*C)**0.5)/2*A))
Phi2 = 2*math.atan((-B-math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A))
print('The Angular displacement of the output link DC in degrees areand', Phi2)
```

but I keep getting this traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\py4e\y.py", line 35, in <module>
    Phi2 = 2*math.atan((-B-math.sqrt(B**2 - 4*A*C))/(2*A))
ValueError: math domain error
```

what can I do?

Comment: Check if you took the sqrt of a negative number

Comment: You're probably going to want to make sure that both `Phi1` and `Phi2` are both degrees or both radians.  But that's a different bug.  @AlexHall is correct.

Comment: you could split calculation in simpler parts - `x1 = B**2 - 4*A*C` , `x2 = math.sqrt(x1)`, etc. and then error should shows you in which part you get problem. And then you can use `print(x1)`, `print(x2)`, etc. to see if you have good values. As @AlexHall mentioned you may use negative value in `math.sqrt()` which is not in its `domain` (and then you get error message `math domain error`). If you run `math.sqrt(-1)` then you get the same error message.